# How to show an object in viewport as it is in another keyframe, without going to that other keyframe?

Tags: animation, keyframes

This is keyframe 1
[image]

This is keyframe 2

[image]

I would like to see the object as it is in another keyframe, without going to that other keyframe. For example, I would like to see the object as it is in keyframe 1, while working in keyframe 2. I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: 0nion-Skinning - Slash add-on (3D) $ https://blendermarket.com/products/slash or Greace pencil (2D) https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/onion_skinning.html

Answer (score 3):

Blender Does not support anything as direct as Onion-skinning like in 2D Animation (without addons at least)
Blender DOES on the other hand, support Motion paths, Which will show you essentially the same information in a more basic way. To Use it, select the object, and find motion paths in the object info tab

[image: Here]

Click Calculate, And it should give you a result like this:

[image]

Hopefully this helps!